# How can I use the blockchain API?

Tags: blockchain

The blockchain is not designed in a way where you can easily get information correct? You have to know more than python basics and have good programming skills as their seems to be no API, and no methods of just querying the data to get basic stats such as "latest transaction" or "biggest transaction ever"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the BlochChain API is pretty good and Ben Reeves has done a nice work implementing it. And for the most part, for free. You only have to know how to send HTTP requests from your code, and parse the Json your app receives. If you think his API is not complete or unworking, do it yourself and make him competition ;-)

An API is designed for **programmers**, not simple users. What do you want to do exactly?